# Disable hover information for a specific layer (geom) of plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), drat)) +
    geom_violin() +
    geom_jitter()
ggplotly(gg)
```

In example code we use `ggplot` to plot violin and jitter layers. `Plotly` displays information for both layers (i.e. when hovered over jitter point it will display specific point information, same thing happens when hovered over the violin plot). However, I want `plotly` to display information only for `geom_jitter`.

**Question:** How to disable hovered information for specific layer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the `hoverinfo` to `"none"` for that `geom`:

```
gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), drat)) +
             geom_violin() +
             geom_jitter()
ggply <- ggplotly(gg)

ggply$x$data[[1]]$hoverinfo <- "none"

ggply
```

[image]

Comment: Lifesaver with this answer! I'd have never figured this out...