# How to fix the hoverinfo error in my shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

I have developed a shiny app using ggplot2 and plotly, however, the hover text was not correctly showed for two horizontal lines which I added as the upper and lower limits. I want to hide the hover text for these two lines. Does anyone know how to achieve it？

I found one solution but it didn't work for shiny
[Disable hover information for a specific layer (geom) of plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801389/disable-hover-information-for-a-specific-layer-geom-of-plotly)

```
  library(shiny)
    shinyServer(

     function(input,output,session){
       reactivelab <- reactive({
           gg <-labn %>% filter(PARCAT2  == input$Group & LBTEST == 
                 input$Par & SUBJID == input$ID) })    

 output$labpot <- renderPlotly({
     req(nrow(reactivelab()) > 0)
     q <- ggplot(data=reactivelab(),aes(x=ADY, y=AVAL))+
        geom_point()+geom_line()+
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept=ANRLO),linetype="longdash")+
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept=ANRHI),linetype="longdash")+
        ylab("Lab Standard Value") + xlab("Lab Test Day") 
        mm <- style(q,  text =  paste("Lab Parameter:", reactivelab()$PARAM,
                                "<br>Lab Test Day:", reactivelab()$ADY,
                                "<br>Lab Standard Value:", reactivelab()$AVAL,
                                "<br>Normal Range Upper Limit:", reactivelab()$ANRHI,
                                "<br>Normal Range Lower Limit:", reactivelab()$ANRLO

  ), hoverinfo = "text")})

 })
```

[image: Shiny App 1]

[image: Shiny App 2]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `style`, you can pass the `text` aesthetic to the `aes` of the `ggplot` function:

```
ggplot(data=reactivelab(), 
       aes(x=ADY, y=AVAL, 
           text = paste("Lab Parameter:", PARAM,
                        "<br>Lab Test Day:", ADY,
                        "<br>Lab Standard Value:", AVAL,
                        "<br>Normal Range Upper Limit:", ANRHI,
                        "<br>Normal Range Lower Limit:", ANRLO)))
```